# Initialize several bash variables with the output of a single command

Tags: bash, variable, read

My goal is to initialize multiple bash variables from the output of one single command. Specifically, line `i` should be the value of variable `i`. Example:

My command is a Python program with the name `init.py`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  print("Value of A")
  print("Value of B")
  print()
  print("Value of D")
```

Desired outcome:

```
echo "A='$A', B='$B', C='$C', D='$D'"
# --> A='Value of A', B='Value of B', C='', D='Value of D'
```

What I then tried without success:

```
read A B C D < <(python init.py)
# --> Effect: A='Value', B='of', C='A', D=''

read -d$'\n' A B C D < <(python init.py)
# --> Effect: A='Value', B='of', C='A', D=''

IFS=$'\n' read A B C D < <(python init.py)
# --> Effect: A='Value of A', B='', C='', D=''

IFS=$'\n' read -d$'\n' A B C D < <(python init.py)
# --> Effect: A='Value of A', B='', C='', D=''
```

1. How to solve this problem?
2. How to generalize this to other separators, such as the Null byte `\0`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an empty line, using `IFS` won't work, because multiple `\n` are squeezed.

However, you can use `readarray`:

```
readarray -t arr < <(python init.py)
echo "A='${arr[0]}', B='${arr[1]}', C='${arr[2]}', D='${arr[3]}'"
```

---

Add `-d ''` to delimit by `\0`:

```
readarray -d '' -t arr < <(python init.py)
```

From `man bash`:

> **-d**     The first character of delim is used to terminate each input line, rather than newline.  If delim is the empty string, mapfile will terminate a line when it reads a NUL character.

Comment: Thanks, that'll work. Can I use `\0` as delimiter too?